# about upload iPhone video to Youtube

Tags: iphone

how to set the video format of the iPhone camera captured? I think that can be mov,mp4, h.2x , because iPhone can play it, but can not find API to set the video format to recording .....

also want upload the video to youtube, anyone know where can find a good open source code for this purpose, I think that this feature will be commonly and it must be done by other coder....just want save time for this purpose ..

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [gdata](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html) is enough

Answer (score 0):

Using gdata is the way to go as Robin mentioned above. Here is a great article that outlines what you need to do and provides a great set of [source code](http://urinieto.com/2010/10/upload-videos-to-youtube-with-iphone-custom-app/) to get you started.

Hope this helps!!