# How to upload video to youtube in app?

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upload a video to YouTube from within an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528568/how-do-i-upload-a-video-to-youtube-from-within-an-ios-application)

I am creating a project, in that project i want to upload video to youtube which captured by my camera . for this i have done so much research on google but i dont find any satisfied answer.

the link i have checked out is...

[How do I upload a video to YouTube from within an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528568/how-do-i-upload-a-video-to-youtube-from-within-an-ios-application)

[Uploading Video with iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065628/uploading-video-with-iphone)

https://github.com/nparry/gdata-objectivec-client/tree/

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#Uploading_Videos

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

[Upload video on youtube from iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801383/upload-video-on-youtube-from-iphone-app)

[Any tutorials for using GData API to upload to video to youtube form iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860923/any-tutorials-for-using-gdata-api-to-upload-to-video-to-youtube-form-ios-app)

[Way to upload video on youtube using ios sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952316/way-to-upload-video-on-youtube-using-ios-sdk)

[How do I upload a video to YouTube from within an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528568/how-do-i-upload-a-video-to-youtube-from-within-an-ios-application)

http://urinieto.com/2010/10/upload-videos-to-youtube-with-iphone-custom-app/

[about upload iPhone video to Youtube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498193/about-upload-iphone-video-to-youtube?rq=1)

[How to upload video to youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108386/how-to-upload-video-to-youtube?rq=1)

[Upload video to YouTube using iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107326/upload-video-to-youtube-using-iphone?rq=1)

And much more that i dont remember.so any one have good tutorial link or any thing that may be helpful please direct me.

**UPDATE**

If i will record video from iphone and send it on server using web service and upload that video thru the web service to youtube than apple allow that?

Comment: ceejayoz ,actually i have checked that link to and that does not contain answer.

Comment: Sure it does. Direct link to the API documentation for doing this.

Comment: Why would it be marked as duplicate of a question that is marked as not constructive and has no good answers?

Comment: Hi lipd, Have you got solution for it?